# Excel Autofill in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: windows

I'm currently doing a cert 3 in bus admin. I'm doing a document in excel and I'm required to do autofill for average, minimum and maximum. Have tried to do a few different things and none of it's working. What is best way for me to do autofill please???

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your excel sheet data that you're trying to use auto fill on? You basically just have to create a formula once and you can use the autofill feature to use the formula with the other data sets.

So if you have multiple columns of data, you first create a new row that contains average, another that contains minimum, and another that contains the maximum. To get these values simple click on the arrow next to the AutoSum feature [image] in the top right corner of the HOME tab and choose the respective calculation. After that is done for one column, you can use the autofill feature by selecting the three column cells and use the fill handle [image] in the bottom right corner of the selected cells. This should use the same formulas on the other columns of data.

Example:
[image]